# Trying to get feed through react native streamer using react native in Android getting error

Tags: android, react-native, gstreamer, gstreamer-1.0, java-gstreamer

I am trying to get the rtp feed through UDP using streamer in react native, I did tried making the bridge using Java and also I am trying react native streamer but not able to do it in Android.
I have installed react native streamer and tried connecting it manually and applied the logic but not getting the fees instead getting the error.

> No matching configuration of project :react-native-gstreamer was found. The consumer was configured to find an API of a component, preferably optimized for Android, as well as attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.BuildTypeAttr' with value 'debug', attribute 'com.android.build.api.attributes.AgpVersionAttr' with value '7.3.1' but:None of the consumable configurations have attributes.